# Keep an internal app updated

Tags: android, android-update-app

I'm going to develop an android app for a museum, which will handle a tablet with the app installed on it to the visitors.
The app will be on foreground *full time* and visitor will only be able to use this app.

Since there will be many tablets, and they are all under our control, I would like a way to update all the tablets remotly with the last version of the app.

Is there a way to achive this?

Comment: On non custom android version there is no way, other than publish app on google play and turning on autoupdates.

Comment: @Federico Ponzi see my answer sir may be this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to achive this?
>
> Answer is : **Yes** but with one exception lets have a look.

**Step 1 :** Create a local server for your museum. I guess it is already in the museum.

**Step 2 :** Now In your android application whenever you start your app check that whether new version of APK is available. For checking APK new version you can use this code.

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
int apkVersion = packageInfo.versionCode;
```

You should set your APK name like "yourAppname_version" so whenever you upload the new app to your local server just change the name so you can easily identify that new version of APK is available or not.

**Step 3 :** If new version is available then start downloading APK from the local server and save it to your storage directory.

**Step 4 :** When downloading completed you can call this set of code to install the new APK.

```
Intent intentApkInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentApkInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"yourAppname_version.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intentApkInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intentApkInstall);
```

Now the Exception part is here the above code will prompt user to install APK. So in this case you have to install it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already found a similar option online, but I'm looking for an automatic way. Thanks anyway